# Adding search button to text input

Tags: css

I'm new in CSS and today I want to add search button to my `navbar textbox`,

So I try something like this:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin:0px;
}

.section-title{
    color: #2ddf5c;
    }


.main-header{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-evenly;
width:100%;
background: #2ddf5c;
padding: 16px;
}

.main-header > div{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.main-header__brand{
color: #0e4f1f;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
}

.main-nav__searchbar_container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.main-nav__searchbar_container input.main-nav__searchbar{
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
  /* background: #2b303b; */
  border: none;
  font-size: 10pt;
  float: left;
  /* color: #fff; */
  padding-left: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.main-nav__searchbar_container input.main-nav__searchbar::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color: #65737e;
}

.main-nav__searchbar_container input.main-nav__searchbar:-moz-placeholder{ /*Frefox 18 */
    color: #65737e;
}
.main-nav__searchbar_container input.main-nav__searchbar::-moz-placeholder{/*Frefox 19 */
    color: #65737e;
}
.main-nav__searchbar_container input.main-nav__searchbar:-ms-input-placeholder{
    color: #65737e;
}
.main-nav__searchbar_container button.icon{
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    background: #232833;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    color: #4f5b66;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 10pt;
    -webkit-transition: all .55s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .55s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .55s ease;
    -o-transition: all .55s ease;
    transition: all .55s ease;
  }

  .main-nav__searchbar_container:hover button.icon, 
  .main-nav__searchbar_container:active button.icon, 
  .main-nav__searchbar_container:focus button.icon{
      outline: none;
      opacity: 1;
      margin-left: -50px;
  }

.main-nav__searchbar_container:hover button.icon:hover{
    background: red;
}
.main-nav__searchbar{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 8px;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: none;
    transition: .3s;
}

.main-nav{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.main-nav__items{
display: flex;
margin:8px;
padding:8px;
list-style: none;
}
.main-nav__item{
    display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav__social{
    display:block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}


.another-container{
margin:auto;
width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>CSS course</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
 <header class="main-header">
            <div>
                <a href="index.html" class="main-header__brand">
                    uHost
                </a></div><nav class="main-nav">
                <div class="another-container">
                    <div class=main-nav__searchbar_container><input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="main-nav__searchbar">
                    <button class="icon"><i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <ul class="main-nav__items">
                    <li class="main-nav__item"> 
                        <img class="main-nav__social" src="navbar-icons/social-media__icons/facebook.svg" alt="facebook">
                    </li>
                    <li class="main-nav__item">
                        <img class="main-nav__social" src="navbar-icons/social-media__icons/instagram-bosquejado.svg" alt="instagram">
                    </li>  
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        </body>
```

So my button appears when you hover the mouse over the `textbox`. Problem is my button element it's not aligned with my `textbox` even though they are in the same container, what am I doing wrong?

Another thing I want to add is to color the border of the `textbox` on my hover action to be part of the design and give the impression the `textbox` is active too something like this:

[image]

I try to use `border-color: #232833;` in hover css rule but that does not work,

Regards

---UPDATE---

I try to wrap all into a new container as comment bellow as:

```
  .another-container
       {
          margin:auto;
          width: 100%;
          padding: 10px;
       }
```

But result is the same.

Comment: Try wrapping both button & textbox inside a container and align to center vertically and horizontally. For border, you can use outine css property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the button alignment, it needs to have the same margin as its sibling `.main-nav__searchbar`, or alternatively, you could apply a padding to the paren't `.main-nav__searchbar_container` instead of a margin to both children.

css for button alignment

```
.main-nav__searchbar_container button.icon {
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

css for adding border to input on hover

```
input.main-nav__searchbar:hover {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```